# Is there a way to style the Suitelet forms that are available without login in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

The default form that we create with suitlet is ugly and I want to style it but I am not finding any way to style its default stylesheet. I was using inline html to do this but its flickering. can we create a complete form using inline html, without using the default?

Answer (score 3):

As prasun indicated, you can return whatever raw HTML you want from a Suitelet, including your own complete CSS. We usually handle this by putting our HTML and CSS files in the file cabinet and placing special tags where we want dynamic information to go. The Suitelet then simply loads these files, replaces the tags accordingly, and returns the full HTML. Simple example might look something like this:

*File Cabinet/SuiteScripts/my-project/myHtml.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Suitelet Report</title>
        <!-- This tag will be replaced with the CSS file; unfortunately, NetSuite does
             not apply the styles if they are included with a link tag -->
        <style>NL_CSS</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="data-desc"><span id="data-month">NL_MONTH</span> <span id="data-year">NL_YEAR</span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

*File Cabinet/SuiteScripts/my-project/myStyles.css:*

```
body {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 1em 1.5em;
}

p#data-desc {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

*File Cabinet/SuiteScripts/my-project/mySuitelet.js:*

```
function onRequest(request, response) {
    // Load the HTML content
    var html = nlapiLoadFile('SuiteScripts/my-project/myHtml.html').getValue();

    // Current date
    var now = moment();

    // Replace the month and year tags with real values
    html = html.replace(/NL_MONTH/, moment.months()[now.month()]);
    html = html.replace(/NL_YEAR/, now.year());

    // Load the CSS file to obtain its URL
    file = nlapiLoadFile('SuiteScripts/my-project/myStyles.css');

    // Replace the NL tag with the CSS contents
    html = html.replace(/NL_CSS/, file.getValue());

    response.write(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to hack NetSuite stylesheet of `nlobjform`, that might not be ideal as NetSuite can change that at any point on time, as it might get dependent on NetSuite's default DOM.

If you want complete style of your own you can embed an iframe in inline html and then style the page entirely with your own style sheet.

If you do not want NetSuite header and menu options as well to appear, then I would suggest you to return complete HTML and stylesheet tags in `response` object.

```
response.setContentType('HTMLDOC');
response.write(HTML_AS_STRING);
```

Comment: can I use my own form? instead of using netsuite with the example above. Can you give a examples please.

Comment: `response.setContentType('HTMLDOC');response.write(HTML_AS_STRING);` Use your form HTML String value as `HTML_AS_STRING`